# Running server-side Bash scripts through CGI

Tags: linux, apache, bash, cgi

Required info:
I am running this off a home PC webserver, Fedora 20 with httpd from yum repo.
I took the base version of my .cgi file from: http://www.instructables.com/id/Simple-linux-commands-from-a-web-page/ and have been trying to modify it for my needs.

My issue - I can very easily make the cgi script run uname, lspci, ls, along with any script in the /usr/bin folder that simply displays text.
I can NOT however, run a script that actually DOES something.. For example, I cannot get the cgi to run "rhythmbox-client --next" to skip forward a song on Rhythmbox Media Player.

My intention: I run a 'music bot' for my friends ventrilo server, and I want to give them (a password protected) way to access the bot from the web, to change songs, add song's to the play queue, ect ect.

The functions (none of which I can get to work) that I need are:
Next Song (rhythmbox-client --next)
Previous Song (rhythmbox-client --previous)
Add Song to queue (rhythmbox-clinet --enqueue NAME)
Clear the song queue (rhythmbox-client --clear-queue
Display currently playing song (rhythmbox-client --print-playing)
Display list of Songs on the computer (ls /home/user/Music | grep ".mp3")

Try as I might, I cannot get ANY of these things to work. I have also tried using Banshee instead of rhythmbox, with the same problem.

The section of the script that is suppose to execute the commands is below:
    echo ""
    echo "The Elite Music Bot Control Panel"
    PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/opt/bin"
    export $PATH
    echo ""
    echo ""

```
# test if any parameters were passed
if [ $CMD ]
then
  case "$CMD" in
    BotInfo)
    echo "<pre>"
      /bin/BotInfo
    echo "System Name:" `/bin/uname -n`
      echo "</pre>"
      ;;

    next)
      echo "Skipped to the next song."
      /bin/rhythmbox-client --next
      ;;

    back)
      echo "Repeating the previous song. <pre>"
      /bin/rhythmbox-client --previous
      echo "</pre>"
      ;;

playing)
      echo "The current song playing is... <pre>"
      rhythmbox-client --print-playing
      echo "</pre>"
      ;;

queue)
      echo "The requested song has been added to the queue. <pre>"
      rhythembox-client --enqueue $QUEUE_SONG
      echo "</pre>"
      ;;

       rating)
          echo "The rating of the current song has been set to $RATING. <pre>"
          /bin/rhythmbox-client --set-rating $RATING
          echo "</pre>"
          ;;
ls)
    echo "<pre>"
    list=`ls /home/USER/Music | grep ".mp3"`
    echo "$list"
    echo "</pre>"
    ;;
     *)
      echo "Unknown command $CMD<br>"
      ;;
  esac
fi
```

The very first one is a simple script that displays system time (date), cpuinfo, meminfo, ect and it DOES work. The others however do not.

I've tried running the bash commands as

```
echo "$(command)"
```

for the print-playing i've tried doing it like:

```
playing=`rhythmbox-client --print-playing`
echo "$playing"
```

I've also tried creating a script that is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "This command worked!"
rhythmbox-client --next
```

I named that rhynext, chmod +x and moved to /usr/bin, when run in terminal it works, when telling the cgi to do  /usr/bin/rhynext  it does nothing.

Please help.

I am smart enough to reverse-engineer code, if you can simply give me a single segment/example of the code that will work I will most likely be able to convert it to my uses. Thanks in advance.

Edit: When running 'next' script for Banshee as the apache user..

```
sudo -u apache /usr/bin/next
[sudo] password for OMMITED: 
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/usr/share/httpd/.config" is denied.
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo:Create ()
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Paths.InitializePaths () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Paths.set_ApplicationName (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.InitializePaths () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Booter.Booter.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/usr/share/httpd/.config" is denied.
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.DirectoryInfo.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.DirectoryInfo:Create ()
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Paths.InitializePaths () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Hyena.Paths.set_ApplicationName (System.String value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Banshee.ServiceStack.Application.InitializePaths () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Booter.Booter.Main () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Have you tried to redirect stderr to a file (to see if any error message appears) ?

Comment: `/bin/rhythmbox-client` might be expecting to connect to the rhythmbox dbus interface of the current user, this cgi will not be able to do that. You might need to manually expose the right dbus session.

Comment: When you test it, run the script as the apache user (e.g. `sudo -u www-data ./yourscript`).

Comment: Etan - How do i do that, because I'm pretty sure you're correct about that, as when I login through ssh I have to run a dbus script before running such commands.

That other guy - I did, I get a whole bunch of errors from that..
Updated original question to show error

Comment: New development - The ls command I have, works if I change the apache user to my username and usergroup, I know this isn't acceptable, but I wanted to see what would happen if I did, so perhaps it's a permissions issue aswell for some of it? How would I allow the apache user to see my music folder for the ls ?  Also - Is there a way to make the ls command list files that are also in subdirectories of the directory chosen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem stemmed from rhythmbox-client expecting to connect to the dbus session of the current user to gather the rhythmbox info/issue commands. (Thanks to Etan Reisner for pointing that out)

After alittle digging online I found the solution.  Create 2 files, one to save the current user's dbus session address into a temp file upon login, and another to call the dbus address and route the CGI command through it.

File 1: Leave in desired folder, add to start items, make executable (chmod +x) name "Get.DBus.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/.DBUS_temp
```

File 2: Make executable, move to /usr/bin, make executable (chmod+x) name "Run.DBus.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/USER/.DBUS_temp
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
$*
```

change the execution command of the desired command in CGI from..

```
command)
  /bin/command
;;
```

TO

```
command)
 /bin/RunDBus.sh /bin/command
;;
```

Problem is solved. All commands work as intended.

Thanks for everyones help, never would have though it was a DBus issue XD